# Run JSHint for a single file in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, jshint

I have JSHint setup with multiple subtasks (src, lib, and test) in Grunt which works great. However, as we're just starting out using this setup there are a *lot* of errors in our many source files.

```
$ grunt jshint:src
... lots of errors ...
```

While working on one file at a time, is it possible to re-lint that single file?

```
$ grunt jshint:src:one.js
... only errors from one.js ...
```

**Update**

One complication is that the watch task *also* has multiple subtasks to fire off different tasks based on which type of file is edited.

```
watch: {
    src: {
        files: [ SRC_DIR + "hgm*.js" ],
        tasks: [ "jshint:src", "test" ]
    },
    lib: {
        files: [ "lib/hgm-test-setup.js", "lib/hgm.loader.js" ],
        tasks: [ "jshint:lib", "test" ]
    },
    test: {
        files: [ "tests/**/*.js" ],
        tasks: [ "jshint:test", "test" ]
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that `src` and `lib` use one `.jshint` while `test` uses a different one that specifies all the globals used for testing such as assertions. I can combine `src` and `lib`, but can I override the JSHint config file for `test`?

Comment: a lot of IDE's (and even text editors like Sublime Text) have a way to plug in jshint. Might this be a better approach for single file?

Comment: @explunit - Many of us use NetBeans, and while there is a [JSLint plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40893/?show=true), it will require work to teach it to use JSHint and our `.jshint` configuration files. I would prefer a solution in Grunt so it addresses all situations.

Comment: @explunit - I did find a [fork that use JSHint](https://github.com/JeClemens/netbeans-jshint), but I would still like a Grunt solution if there is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [grunt-contrib-watch-task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#compiling-files-as-needed), provides an example how to configure your tasks, and use the watch-event for linting only changed files:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    scripts: {
      files: ['lib/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint'],
      options: {
        nospawn: true,
      },
    },
  },
  jshint: {
    all: ['lib/*.js'],
  },
});

// on watch events configure jshint:all to only run on changed file
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  grunt.config(['jshint', 'all'], filepath);
});
```

Comment: I'm going to try this now as it gets me closer, but is there a way to override more than the file path in the event based on which watch subtask was triggered? See my edit for how the watch subtasks are setup and why.

Comment: of course you can get and set everything in your config. set [grunt.config.get/grunt.config.set](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.get)

Comment: Yes, but I need to alter the config based on which watch subtask fired, i.e., which file was edited. I look for `src` and `test` in the name of the modified file which is all well and good until someone writes a source with "test" in the name or vice versa.

Comment: i dont see how you can do that with grunt-contrib-watch or grunt itself, sorry. i think you'll need to code that. i would try to use something like [grunt.file.expand/expandMapping](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) and see if your filepath is included in that "expanded" array (maybe you have to slice off the extname of the file)

Comment: Is there anyway to have this, or similar functionality, with `spawn: true`?

Comment: i don't know why that shouldn*t work without the nospawn option set

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer above is not really what I was expecting or looking for I'd like to offer this answer…

You can invoke it like `grunt jshint-file:src/filename.js`

```
grunt.registerTask('jshint-file',
        'Runs jshint on a file',
        function (filePath) {
            var reportFunc = require('jshint/src/reporters/unix').reporter
            var optionsString = grunt.file.read('.jshintrc')
            var options = JSON.parse(optionsString)
            jshint(grunt.file.read(filePath), options)
            errors = jshint.data().errors.map(function (error) {
                var record = {};
                record.file = filePath;
                record.error = error;
                return record;
            });
            console.log(reportFunc(errors))
        }
    )
```